# How to fetch partial data from JSON in mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have a json and want to retrieve partial data. How can I achieve it through mule4

Input:

```
   {
  "customerID": [
    {
      "name": "customerID",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": []
    }
  ],
  "companyname": [
    {
      "name": "companyname",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": []
    }
  ],
  "orders": [
    {
      "name": "orders",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": []            
      }
  ]
}
```

Output: want to fetch only customerID and companyname

```
{
  "customerID": [
    {
      "name": "customerID",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": []
    }
  ],
  "companyname": [
    {
      "name": "companyname",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can create an object with that data:

```
output application/json
---
{
    customerID: payload.customerID,
    companyname: payload.companyname
}
```

Or remove the `orders` key (but this won't scale if you have more keys):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
vars - 'orders'
```

You could also filter the keys you do want, for example.

Output:

```
{
  "customerID": [
    {
      "name": "customerID",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "companyname": [
    {
      "name": "companyname",
      "alias": "null",
      "arguments": [

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```